# DRF generate html to pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Im trying to generate pdf from given html file but `get_template` function is not working i guess.

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.template.loader import get_template
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
```

```
def render_to_pdf(context_dict={}):
    try:
        template = get_template('invoice.html')
        html  = template.render(context_dict)
        result = BytesIO()
        pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
        if not pdf.err:
            return result.getvalue()
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR', e)
```

The Except block returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Change line to:

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result)
```

Comment: Its no the problem in that line. Its the problem with 'get_template' function

Comment: and I cant seem to fix it

Answer (score 0):

It was my logical error issue. I didn't added 'templates' folder to `DIRS` in settings.py file.